# Why is a screwdriver a "destornillador"?

Tags: etimología

A screw is a *tornillo*, and the tool used to put one into something is a *destornillador*.  This has always confused me, because *des-* is a negating prefix.  This means that the tool is referred to is an "un-screwer" or "screw remover" in Spanish, which logically can't be its primary use because you can't unscrew more screws than have been screwed in in the first place.

Why is it called that, rather than *tornillador*?

Comment: The action called to remove a screw is *desatornillar*. (= revome the screw from the surface where placed.) *Atornillar* is the action to place the screw in the surface. Either *atornillador* or *desatornillador* work as a unique tool to perform both actions.

Comment: It's even more puzzling to me why in Spain they call "tirafondos" what we call "tornillos". Maybe I should write a question about it.

Comment: It's called that to make it harder for poor old English speakers like me to get their tongues round it. _atornillador_ would be too easy.

Comment: The comment from @Ustanak should be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Im spanish and I would never asked myself that haha Maybe it is because you usually need one to un-screw something that came screwed from the store.

Comment: Apparently, destornilladores were invented way before tornillos : ) [¿Por qué fue primero el tornillo y después el destornillador?](http://www.porque.es/por-que-fue-primero-el-tornillo-y-despues-el-destornillador/)

Answer (score 4):

`des` is not necessarily negative but an action that could be done or undone. See the definition of `destornillador` by the *Real Academia de la Lengua Española*:

*Instrumento de hierro u otra materia, que sirve para destornillar y atornillar.* http://dle.rae.es/?id=DUVd5lp

Other name for the tool is `atornillador` where we have something like a positive action. See the *Real Academia de la Lengua Española* http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ITCeKd

Comment: I think this might be a fine answer, but it should be authoritative rather than suggesting "maybe." This means it should probably be validated as correct, and then stated as so, ideally linking to an official source.

Comment: I barely heard "atornillador". If exists as a word it's really uncommon to hear or say it. At least in Bolivia. Good answer, though.